# simple combinatorics question - what did I do wrong?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I was asked the following question. I solved it, I thought my solution is correct, but it turns out I was mistaken, I'd like to know why.

Question: How many ways are to order 4 sets $(A,B,C,D)$ such that $A,B,C,D \subseteq \{1,2,...,n\}$ and $A\cup B\cup C\cup D=\{1,2,...,n\}$?

My answer: Firstly, there are $4!$ ways to order 4 sets "in a row" so to speak, and so we will multiply our final answer by $4!$.

Now, each number from $\{1,2,...,n\}$ has 4 different options, so that's $4^n$ combinations. multiply that by $4!$ and my answer is $4^n4!$

Correct answer: $15^n$

Comment: Do you really mean 100, not n in the union?

Comment: I did mean $n$ its a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each element of the set {1,2,...,n} can be in any combination of the sets of which there are 15 possibilities. For example 1 could be in all of A,B,C and D or just A and B or some other combination. Thus, there are 15 possible combinations to put each element as one choosing at least 1 of the 4 sets and at most all 4 sets for each element.

If you want the breakdown in terms of those 15 possibilities, consider how many sets one is putting an element in:

All 4 sets: 1 possible combination.

3 of the 4 sets: 4 combinations as one set is left out.

2 of the 4 sets: 6 combinations as this is 4 choose 2.

1 of the 4 sets: 4 combinations as just one is being picked.

Total: 15 options for each element.